# Adding Columns to a table

Tags: custom-fieldtype, custom-field, table-field, plugin-supertable, table

Is there a way or a plugin that allows you to add columns and change columns heading from within the entry? Instead of defining column heading while creating the table field. It would be nice to have the ability to add/delete columns and have the table be dynamic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the [supercool](http://plugins.supercooldesign.co.uk/plugin/table-maker/licence) table maker you can create dynamic tables. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: YES! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

I used the method described here: "A User-Friendly Table Field" http://www.drivesimplicity.com/blog/a-user-friendly-table-field -- instruct the user to leave columns that he/she doesn't want blank and to use the first row as his/her column headings. I've found that it works quite well!

Comment: Editors are still not able to edit more than a certain amount of columns that way